# How to mock/stub object with polymorphic association and save! in callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have following controller spec which passes. 
But I would like to replace  `create(:link)` object with mock or stubs. 
How can I get around `after_create` callback `update_target`.

Now when Im trying to `mock_model(Link)` I get error:

`` undefined method `save!' for nil:NilClass `` when spec trying create landing object.

```
describe LandingsController do
  describe "#destroy" do

    before(:each) do
      controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(mock_model(User))
      stub_request(:any, "www.example.com").to_return(status: 200)
      @link = create(:link)
    end

    let(:landing) do 
      create(:landing, target_id: @link.id)
    end

    it "destroys the landing" do
      Landing.should_receive(:find).with(landing.id.to_s).and_return(landing)
      landing.should_receive(:destroy).and_return(true)
      delete :destroy, id: landing.id, format: :json
    end

    it "returns 204" do
      delete :destroy, id: landing.id, format: :json
      response.status.should == 204
    end
  end
end

class Landing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true
  ...
  after_create :update_target
  before_destroy :update_target

  def update_target
    self.target.save!
  end
end

# landings_controller.rb
  respond_to :json

  def destroy
    landing = Landing.find(params[:id])
    target = landing.target
    landing.destroy
    target.save!
    respond_with landing
  end
```

Maybe I should mock also landing object. But how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
let(:landing) do 
  mock(:landing, target_id: @link.id, destroy: true)
end
```

solve your problem?

Comment: I would like to not create(:link) using factory for that spec. Your answer gives me error: ``Mock :tagging received unexpected message :id with (no args)`` in line: ``Failure/Error: Tagging.should_receive(:find).with(tagging.id.to_s).and_return(tagging)``